# Laravel model for Place that can have aliases (=duplicate entries) - how to treat them as one

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The GPS data I import can have multiple waypoint places for the same place.
I store this GPS data in the database, but want to treat all duplicates as one.

My Laravel (v6) model Place has `id` and `parent_id` (I could change this if necessary). E.g.

```
id parent_id name
1  null      real place
2  1         same as real place
```

When querying for Place info, I would always like to do this for the real place *and* the duplicates.
So far I am using a local scope:

```
    public function scopeId($query, $id) {
        return $query->where('id', $id)->orWhere('parent_id', $id);
    }
```

This allows me to do e.g. `Place::id(1)->with('visits')->get()` which gives me e.g.

```
place 1
 - visit A
 - visit B
place 2
 - visit C
```

Is there a way to "merge" these Places so that the responses always return just the parent Place?
Like:

```
place 1
 - visit A
 - visit B
 - visit C
```

The `with('visits')` is an example. Would like this functionality to apply to all Place related queries.

Edit: full example

```
Place::id(1078)->select('id','parent_id')->with('visits:id,place_id')->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3092
     all: [
       App\Place {#3115
         id: 1068,
         parent_id: 1078,
         visits: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3109
           all: [
             App\Timeline {#3087
               id: 8022,
               place_id: 1068,
             },
             App\Timeline {#3094
               id: 8023,
               place_id: 1068,
             },
           ],
         },
       },
       App\Place {#3137
         id: 1078,
         parent_id: null,
         visits: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3139
           all: [
             App\Timeline {#3117
               id: 8304,
               place_id: 1078,
             },
             App\Timeline {#3084
               id: 8401,
               place_id: 1078,
             },
             App\Timeline {#3116
               id: 8513,
               place_id: 1078,
             },
             App\Timeline {#3119
               id: 9363,
               place_id: 1078,
             },
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: I understand that you want to combine the output returned by `Place::id(1)->with('visits')->get()`  can you post the `dd()` of `Place::id(1)->with('visits')->get()`?

Comment: added example to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **You can override the `get()` method from Eloquent by creating a new class `CustomQueryBuilder` that extends the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`:**

   Your customized `get()` method in `CustomQueryBuilder`:

   ```
   <?php
    namespace App\Override;

   class CustomQueryBuilder extends \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {

       private $needVisitsCombined = false;

       public function needVisitsCombined() {
               $this->needVisitsCombined = true;
               return $this;
       }

       //@Override
       public function get($columns = ['*']) {
           //Get the raw query string with the PDO bindings
           $originalResult = parent::get($columns);

           if($this->needVisitsCombined == false){
               return $originalResult;
           }

           $parentRecord = $originalResult->filter(function ($result, $key) {
               return $result->parent_id != null;
           });

           $originalResult->each(function ($result, $key) {
               if($result->parent_id == null) {
                   $parentRecord->visits()->concat($result->visits())
               }
           });

           return $parentRecord;

       }
   } 
   ?>
   ```
2. **Create a new class `CustomModel` that extends the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and there override the `newBaseQueryBuilder` like this:**

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App\Override;

   use App\Override\CustomQueryBuilder;

   class CustomModel extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

       //@Override
       protected function newBaseQueryBuilder()
       {
           $connection = $this->getConnection();

           return new CustomQueryBuilder(
               $connection, $connection->getQueryGrammar(), $connection>getPostProcessor(), $this
           );
      }
   }
   ?>
   ```
3. **Finally, Now your Place Model ( or Whichever require this custom `get()` behavior) can extend `CustomModel` instead.**
4. **Now your query will be something like:**

   ```
   Place::id(1)->needVisitsCombined()->with('visits')->get()
   ```

#### Note:

Be aware that all queries made from Models extending your `CustomModel` will get this new behavior, hence I have added a check with `needVisitsCombined()` method.

So if you're doing more customization do all the needed checks to don't mess up with Eloquent normal behaviour, something like this

Comment: @wivku No problem. Keep on coding and you'll get there soon enough :)

Comment: Would it be possible to make this generic for all relations? Visits was an example, a Place can belong to Events, has Categories, etc. I would like to make this generic for all relations, and use that custom Model also for other Models that have parent-child structure. And how would I handle withCount()?

Comment: And ideally, but that maybe too much, in my original question I picked a single Place. Would be great if all this can be generic for multiple Places. E.g. `Place::where(‘id’,’<‘,100)->groupByParent()->with(‘visits’,’categories’)->withCount(‘events’)->get()`